# Override font size in a DIV using CSS

Tags: css, html, overriding, font-size

In a DIV I place some text/html code which get loaded from a database. This text sometimes contains font size definitions (ex: font size="3"). is there a way to override this font size in this specific DIV using CSS.

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: You could always try `!important`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming mark-up similar to the following:

```
<div>
    <font size="1">Some text at 'size="1"'</font> and natively-sized text, with more at <font size="26">'size="26".'</font>
</div>​
```

Then you can explicitly instruct CSS to `inherit` the `font-size` from the parent element:

```
div {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
div font {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MTLtq/).

Please note, of course, that `font` is deprecated and should, therefore, not be used (as support for the element can stop without notice, and/or implementations change without warning).

Incidentally, while `!important` will force a declaration to override the usual cascade of styles, it's taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut; and, if it can be avoided (and in this case, it seems, it *can* be avoided) it should be, since it complicates later debugging of styles, and associated inheritance problems.

Further, this is treating the symptom of your problem; the problem you're really facing is the presence of the `font` tags in your content/database. This should be corrected, by removing the elements, and replacing them with appropriately-styled elements, such as `em`, `span` and so forth...

References:

- [`font` element, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT).
- [`font` element at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/font).

Comment: +'d, a very nice insight on the subject!

Comment: Using `font-size: 100%` is more effective (wider browser support) than `font-size: inherit`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [CSS !important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) notation you are telling the browser to overwrite any font-size defined inside your `div`:

**From the above link it reads:**

> However, for balance, an "!important" declaration (the delimiter token "!" and keyword "important" follow the declaration) takes precedence over a normal declaration.

**Example**

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/4kJY2/) Example!

```
.htmlContents * {font-size:10px!important;}

<div class="htmlContents">my database html content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea: give these text tags an id or class, then use JavaScript to find these elements and change the style on them.

Answer (score 0):

How about stripping the "font" tags from the text before inserting into the div?  Then just style the div with a font size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks had same problem couldn't override font-size of footer of a nested element a.

```
.footer ul li a {

    font-size: 20px ;
    height: 25px;
}
```